# Python Hash: Function to determine longest probe sequence

Tags: python, hash

I am trying to write a function that returns a list of the worst index/indices of a hash table of a certain size. It should resemble:

```
def worst_indices(size_of_hashtable, list_of_keys):
    ....
```

Where list_of_keys is a list of keys that were entered into a hashtable based on the hash function:  h(key) = key % size.

My function does not, however need to output the hash table, it just needs to output the indices that would require the most shifts/probes if you wanted to enter another key into them.

For example, the following code

```
values = [25, 32, 88, 10, 35, 11]  
worst = worst_indices(11, values)  
print(worst)
```

should produce the output:

```
[10]
```

As another example, the code:

```
values = [4, 9, 12, 3, 7, 26, 16, 20, 11]  
worst = worst_indices(13, values)  
print(worst)
```

should produce the output:

```
[3, 7, 11]
```

So if you were to add another value into the hash tables, adding a value into those "worst indices" would result in the most shifting right as it probes for the next open spot. 
   
Any help or tips as to how this could be done would be awesome. 
Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a fun assignment. But in its current state your question is too broad for SO. You need to make a start on it and post some code. But here's a hint or two to get you started:  I'm pretty sure that you _do_ need to actually construct the hash table and insert the keys into it, because which key(s) is/are worst depends on the order of key insertion. You could use a simple list of [key, value] lists for your hash table. And you can make it neat by putting it into a class (if you know how to do classes), but that's not strictly necessary, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your intent, this should solve your problem.  Note that the order in which the values in key_list are added shouldn't affect the result (although it would, of course, affect the bucket assignments in the actual hash table):

```
def worst_indices(hash_size, key_list):
    # require at least one empty hash bucket
    assert(len(key_list) < hash_size)

    buckets = [False] * hash_size
    for key in key_list:
        index = key % hash_size
        index2 = index
        while buckets[index2]:
            index2 += 1
            if index2 == hash_size:
                index2 = 0
        buckets[index2] = True

    # find some empty bucket
    ix0 = buckets.index(False)

    # count the chain lengths
    lengths = [None] * hash_size
    ix = ix0
    length = 0
    while True:
        length = length + 1 if buckets[ix] else 0
        lengths[ix] = length
        ix = hash_size - 1 if ix == 0 else ix - 1
        if ix == ix0:
            break

    max_length = max(lengths)

    return [ix for ix in xrange(hash_size)
               if lengths[ix] == max_length]
```

Here's the output:

```
>>> worst_indices(11, [25, 32, 88, 10, 35, 11])
[10]
>>> worst_indices(13, [4, 9, 12, 3, 7, 26, 16, 20, 11])
[3, 7, 11]
>>>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice code, assuming `key_list` contains no dupes (but that's easy enough to handle). However, many SO regulars don't think it's a good idea to give complete working solutions to suspected homework problems. But hopefully Newbie won't just hand in your code as their own, and will make some attempt to understand it & learn from it...

Comment: Oops, sorry, that never even occurred to me.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much, it's not _that_ big a deal (and there are plenty of regulars who don't follow the "don't do people's homework for them" philosophy). Just bear it in mind for next time. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow!